# UpdateModel does not work when declaring type is different

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is code example of what i am asking.

```
    public ActionResult Action()
    {
        object person = new Person(); //It works if i replace object with Person
        UpdateModel(person); //this does not update person because of "object" declaring type

        return View();
    }
```

What is best way to update model if if i determine model type at runtime ?

Comment: See it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436822/update-model-from-database-does-not-see-a-type-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve at runtime (although not evident why you'd need to, from what you've posted), then use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic person = new Person();   // resolves at runtime -- no point in doing this,
                                 // since the type is known at compile time anyway
```

Comment: var keyword is not related to runtime. Dynamic keywords works quite ok. So can you please update your answer for clear answer.

Comment: :) it is one of the rare case that dynamic keyword handle problem in best way